# How to access value from the dictionary of tuples in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, tuples, key-value

I have a dict with some types of characteristics for cars. I can't understand how to get a specific parameter for the current car. For example, I need to print jast a value "range" for the car "Ford".  But I can get only a full tuple. The code is located below.

```
import Foundation        
let fuelNeed = 10.0        
let carEffect: [String : (coef: Double, range: Double, passengers: Int)] = ["Ford" : (1.0 , 450, 9), "Honda" : (0.97 , 550, 5), "BMW" : (0.5 , 300, 4)]
print(carEffect["Ford"])
```

And the answer will be "(coef: 1.0, range: 450.0, passengers: 9)"
How to get only 450?

Comment: Use .1 or .range to access the second element of your tuple

Comment: Using a struct instead of a tuple would make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should access the member using dot notation like

```swift
carEffect["Ford"]?.range
```

Notice `?` since the value returned by dict may be nil